# HTML5 Line not working using svg

Tags: html, svg, line

I tried to learn HTML5 so i got the code and tried it but i have problem that i am able to get the circle correctly but line didn't display. I tried it to open on Chrome Firefox and IE but none of browser display line while circle was ok!

The code is -

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" id="ls">
<line id="ls" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="100" style="stroke"red; stroke-width:100" />
</svg>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo: **style="stroke"red;**

the correct code is (mind the (semi-) colons):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" id="ls">
<line id="ls" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="100" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:100" />
</svg>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9sat/

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra double-quote in the `style` attribute:

```
style="stroke"red; stroke-width:100"
```